# VBA macro not working for every worksheet, only one

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub SGAFilterShow()
Dim b As Worksheet
For Each b In Worksheets
       b.Outline.ShowLevels ColumnLevels:=2
       b.Range("A5:AL110").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Show"
       b.Outline.ShowLevels ColumnLevels:=1
    Next b
End Sub
```

I want to: For every worksheet, (1) expand all column groups, (2) apply a filter value, (3) and then collapse the group for every worksheet in my workbook.

However, when I run the macro it only works for the first worksheet and ignores the other ones.

I am new to VBA and I do not know why the above code is not working for every worksheet in my workbook.

Comment: Maybe `b.Range("A5:AL110").AutoFilter`...

Comment: I have tried that as well and it's still not working

Comment: If I remember rightly macros can be stored in the file itself or in a location available for all files.

Comment: based on your code, I don't think it's possible to answer. Please debug your code and share with us where it's not behaving as expected. (e.g. stops after first worksheet, gives error, does steps but nothing happens...)

Comment: It is erroring out at the second step where I am calling the range b.Range.

Run-time Error '1004': This can't be applied to the selected range Select a single cell in the range and try again.

Comment: based on the error message, please try to put `b.Range("A1").Select` as the first line in your loop.

Comment: The code works when I test it on 5 worksheets. I can force it to error by emptying cell A5 on one of the sheets though. Is it possible one of your sheets has nothing in A5? Perhaps a hidden sheet, as you're not filtering those out..?

Answer (score 0):

I made a test file and your code works, maybe it is about the range, you should define it in a way that is more dynamic, since you can't always be sure that your sheets have the same amount of columns an rows filled with data.

Try this:

```
    Sub SGAFilterShow()
    Dim b As Worksheet
    For Each b In Worksheets
        b.Outline.ShowLevels ColumnLevels:=2
        b.Range("A5").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Show"
        b.Outline.ShowLevels ColumnLevels:=1
    Next b
    End Sub
```

[Test file](https://orellanaconsulting-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/melvin_orellana_tech/ERqQ30LqOaxJjrCjDUhJW7EBchD7rKdblCxB8aSGUIybEw?e=ets3sX)